# Bootstrap swap div responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I use Bootstrap framework to create my layout.
What I'm trying to achieve is something like this (sorry I can't insert the image here):
[Layout](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6oi-KmqsfrkakkwTElibWp5Y0E/view?usp=sharing)

So far, I only managed to create correctly either the browser or the mobile only. I can't make the layout change from browser to mobile properly.

At the moment, I'm using this code:

```
<div id="main-content" class="container">
    <div class="row no-padding">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 red">Red container</div>     
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 blue">Blue container</div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 green">Green container</div>     
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 orange">Orange container</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem with this code is that the Orange container position become parallel with Green container (causing quite a gap between Blue and Orange), while I want the Orange container directly below Blue container.

I've found a solution which is to duplicate the container and use visible-* to show or hide based on the media size but I don't think it's a very clean solution. If possible I'd like to use CSS-only solution, not using js.

I'd really appreciate any help for this problem.
Thank you very much!

Edit:
I've recreate the layout in this link: http://www.bootply.com/C97SCp3Wcn

Comment: not getting you ..With the code you have posted orange container is below blue [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bhagya/5515joh5/)

Comment: Sorry if it's not clear, kinda hard to explain.  Based on my code, the layout become like this [link]https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6oi-Kmqsfrkdzc4YWNJNkplbDg/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Bhagya now increase the red container height and you will see the Astarthe's problem (I think)

Comment: @P.Santos Yes, you're right. The container has different height. Roughly the height for each container is similar to the attached sample.jpg image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look here

```
<div class="row">

     <div class="col-lg-8 col-xs-12">

         <div class="row">

             <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
                 red
             </div>

             <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
                 blue
             </div>
         </div>

     </div>


     <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-12">

         <div class="row">

             <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
                 green
             </div>

             <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
                 orange
             </div>
         </div>

     </div>

</div>
```

This works.

Explanation:

You have to create two colums `lg-8` and `lg4` for desktop screens and `xs-12` for mobile screens. Inside this columns you can create the colored rows. This nested structure (two rows in a row) is necessary because the outer colums dont have the same height.

**Update**:

I have two options for you.
Without Javascript and bootstrap only, but a minimum redudant.
See here: http://www.bootply.com/b4PCoVthvm

Or you can use javascript (masonry) in combination with bootstrap. See here http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: Thank you very much!  It works!  Really appreciate the answer and the explanation

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice previously. But, in mobile view, I need to swap the order of Blue and Green. Actually that's the real problem. Is it possible to do so?

Comment: I notice that push and pull applies for column in one row. The Blue and Green position is actually in a different row. Is it possible to apply it?

Comment: Yea, I think those two are the only possible options.  Thank you very much, really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Try this Answer...Hope it will work for u

This one is for desktop version

```
<div id="main-content" class="container visible-desktop">
    <div class="row no-padding">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 red">Red container</div>     
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 blue">Blue container</div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 green">Green container</div>     
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 orange">Orange container</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and for mobile version

```
<div id="main-content" class="container visible-phone">
    <div class="row no-padding">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 red">Red container</div>     
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 blue">Blue container</div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 orange">Orange container</div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 green">Green container</div>     

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you mean to create two main-content, each for desktop and mobile? If possible I'd like to keep the same code (no clone or duplicate)

Comment: Ya...But one is visible to desktop version and another one is for mobile..its never duplicate

Comment: Yes, I understand. I'm just wondering if there's a way to achieve it without making two version of code (one for desktop and one for mobile)

Answer (score 0):

You have to write your own custom css to achieve this.Put your own code inside boostrap media query to achieve your layout.
Example:-

```
/* Custom, iPhone Retina */ 
    @media only screen and (min-width : 320px) {
        //your css code
    }

    /* Extra Small Devices, Phones */ 
    @media only screen and (min-width : 480px) {
        //your css code

    }

    /* Small Devices, Tablets */
    @media only screen and (min-width : 768px) {

    }

    /* Medium Devices, Desktops */
    @media only screen and (min-width : 992px) {
        //your css code


    }

    /* Large Devices, Wide Screens */
    @media only screen and (min-width : 1200px) {
        //your css code

    }
```